# Typo3 Content Element generates serverpath instead of domain Path for the CE-Wizard-Icon

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

i updated my Typo3 from 6.2 to 7.6 and now i get the wrong path in the CE-Tab for my Elements (Fluid). 
When i use this line:

```
<flux:form wizardTab="Struktur Elemente" id="modulbox" >
```

i get the following path generated in the CE Wizard:

```
/kunden/xxxx/rp-hosting/xxx/xxx/typo3cms/staging/typo3conf/ext/cmag_website/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Modulbox.png (filepath)
```

When i click on the content element the icon is linked as it should:

```
../typo3conf/ext/cmag_website/Resources/Public/Icons/Content/Modulbox.png
```

Because of this i get this in the CE Wizard: 
[image]

and in the content element itself this (as it should be):
[image]

Can anyone help me?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Which flux version do you use?

I don't know if this solves anything, but since flux 7.1.1 "wizardTab" is deprecated.

- Use `options="{group: 'GroupName'}` or the `flux:form.option.group`
  ViewHelper
- Use `options="{icon: 'iconreference'}"` or the
  `flux:form.option.icon` ViewHelper for icons

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/FormViewHelper.html